# "Cannot GET /(webpage name)" issue with 'Live Server' Extension by Ritwick Dey on VSC

Tags: html

I am writing HTML on Visual Studio Code.
I utilize the extension 'Live Server' by Ritwick Dey to see the output of my work. The live server extension opens a tab on Safari to show the output.
My laptop runs on MacOS.

Upon clicking a hyperlink on the live server tab, 1 new tab opens with the text:
' **Cannot GET /www.youtube.com/@_AR4_** '
on the page.

The address of that tab is:
' **[http://127.0.0.1:5500/www.youtube.com/@\_AR4\_](http://127.0.0.1:5500/www.youtube.com/@%5C_AR4%5C_)** '.

I have written this code for a hyperlink to a webpage, as shown in the bold text below.

**<a href="www.youtube.com/@_AR4_" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">yt/@_AR4_</a>**

I then changed the code to the bold text below. But it also returned the same 'Cannot GET' page.

**<a href="www.youtube.com/@_AR4_">yt/@_AR4_</a>**

I was hoping that upon clicking the hyperlink in the initial live server tab, a new tab of the actual webpage would open.

What should I do in order to successfully create a hyperlink?

Comment: You should use an absolute link: `https://www.youtube.com/@AR4`.

Comment: @DallogFheir it is successful ~ thank you so much :D